# Block to select options if quantity not selected, auto-update the price if quantity has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to get the options in this example to work well, but I need some help/tips from you.

1. How to block selecting the desired options if the quantity is not selected.
2. Is there a way to auto-update/live-update the price/calculations for selected type of paper option when the quantity is changed?
3. Why in my example do I need to press double-click on the desired paper option button to re-calculate the correct price for subtotal? If I press it once the subtotal price is not changing.

***You can check the demo and you will understand what I mean.***

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/c7b5f5t9/

I'm new to jQuery. Thank you in advance.

**Html code:**

```
<h3>Select Quantity:</h3>
    <select name="quantity-select" id="quantity" onchange="subtotal()">
    <option data-price="0.00" value="0" selected>Select Quantity</option>
    <option data-price="1.49" value="55" >55 Flyers for 81.95$ / 1.49$ each</option>
    <option data-price="1.39" value="66" >66 Flyers for 91.74$ / 1.29$ each</option>
    <option data-price="1.29" value="77" >77 Flyers for 99.33$ / 1.09$ each</option>
    <option data-price="1.19" value="88" >88 Flyers for 104.72$ / 0.89$ each</option>
    </select>

<h3>Select Paper:</h3>
    <ul class="paper">
    <li data-price="0.00" onclick="subtotal()">Standard Paper<br>(+0.00$)</li>
    <li data-price="0.15" onclick="subtotal()">Double Thick Paper<br>(+0.15$/piece)</li>
    <li data-price="0.25" onclick="subtotal()">Triple Thick Paper<br>(+0.25$/piece)</li>
</ul>

<h3>Extra Options:</h3>
    <input name="box1" value="nolaminating" id="nolaminating" data-price="0.00" type="radio" onchange="subtotal()">No Laminating (+0.00$)<br>
    <input name="box1" value="matte" id="matte" data-price="50.00" type="radio" onchange="subtotal()">Matte Laminating (+50.00$)<br>
    <input name="box1" value="gloss" id="gloss" data-price="75.00" type="radio" onchange="subtotal()">Gloss Laminating (+75.00$)<br>


<div class="prices"> 

    <h3>Flyers = $<span class="sum" id="flyers">0.00</span></h3>
    <h3>Paper = $<span class="sum" id="papertype">0.00</span></h3>
    <h3>Extra Options = $<span class="sum" id="extraoptions">0.00</span></h3>

</div>

<h3>Subtotal = $<span id="subtotal">0.00</span></h3>
```

**Script code:**

```
var flyersprice = '0.00';
var paperoptions = '0.00';
var extraoptions = '0.00';

function subtotal(){

    var price = $("#quantity option:selected").attr("data-price");

    flyersprice = $("#quantity option:selected").val() * price;

    $("#flyers").text(flyersprice.toFixed(2));

    $(".paper li").click(function(){
        var paperoptions = $(this).data("price") * $("#quantity option:selected").val();
        $("#papertype").text(paperoptions.toFixed(2));
    });
    $('#papertype').change(subtotal);

    $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
        var extraoptions = $(this).data("price");
        $("#extraoptions").text(extraoptions);
    });
    $('input').change(subtotal);

    var sum = 0;
    $('.sum').each(function() {
      sum += +$(this).text();    
    });
    $("#subtotal").text(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: You can make a check based on value of quantity, to set `input[type=radio]` to disabled. `$(input[type=radio]).prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: @lolka_bolka - will try to implement your idea. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to block selecting the desired options if the quantity is not selected.

you don't need to do that, see demo below

> Is there a way to auto-update/live-update the price/calculations for selected type of paper option when the quantity is changed?

yes, you have just to keep values of these inputs

> Why in my example do I need to press double-click on the desired paper option button to re-calculate the correct price for subtotal? If I press it once the subtotal price is not changing.

this is normal, because you put two events on the same button "onclick" + "bind"

that's what you need to do

```
    var selectedPaper = null;    
function subtotal(){
        var price=  $("#quantity option:selected").attr("data-price");
        if($("#quantity").val() == 0){
            $("#papertype").text("0.00");
            $("#extraoptions").text("0.00");
            $("input[type=radio]").attr('checked',false)
            selectedPaper = null;
        }
        flyersprice = $("#quantity").val() * price;
        $("#flyers").text(flyersprice.toFixed(2));

        var sum = 0;
        $('.sum').each(function() {
          sum += +$(this).text();    
        });
        $("#subtotal").text(sum.toFixed(2));
   }
$(function(){
     $("#quantity").on('change',function(){ 
        if(selectedPaper){
            $(".paper li").eq(selectedPaper).trigger('click');
        }
        subtotal();
     });  
     $(".paper li").on('click',function(){
       if($("#quantity").val() != 0){
          var paperoptions = $(this).data("price") * $("#quantity").val();
          $("#papertype").text(paperoptions.toFixed(2));
           selectedPaper = $(".paper li").index(this);
           subtotal();
        }else{
             $("#papertype").text("0.00");
            selectedPaper = null;
        }
     });  
     $("input[type=radio]").on('change',function(){
       if($("#quantity").val() != 0){
            var extraoptions = $(this).data("price");
            $("#extraoptions").text(extraoptions);
           subtotal();
        }else{
             $("#extraoptions").text("0.00");
            selectedPaper = null;
        }
     });
})
```

This a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/veb4oypc/4/)

Comment: @abdallah-arfak - your example is good as you solved the double-click issue, but the `Paper` price is not getting updated when the quantity is changed, the price remains for the old quantity => in result I need to press the button again to calculte the right price.

Comment: @abdallah-arfak - How to make the price for selected paper to be live-updating, for example I have selected `55 flyers`, if I select `double thick paper` option this will be `$8.25` for `Paper price`, but if I change now the quantity to `66 flyers`, the price will remain the same `$8.25` as for `55 flyers` => in result I have to press the desired option button again to calculate the correct price for `66 flyers`. Hope you understand what I mean :)

Comment: @abdallah-arfak - Now the price is updating only for `Paper`, but the `Subtotal` price remains the same - it's not updating, but anyway thank you for your support.

Comment: exactly the trigger of paper should be in quantity event not in subTotal, the demo is updated http://jsfiddle.net/veb4oypc/3/

Comment: @abdallah-arfak - yeah I know, I want to ask you the last question, why the value of `Paper` and `Extra options` become `0` instead of `0.00` when for example I choose no quantity?

Comment: you have to change this .text(0.00); => to this .text("0.00");

http://jsfiddle.net/veb4oypc/4/